# What happens to your AWS CLI when you migrate Macbook content to a new Mac?

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, aws-cli, apple-m1

I recently installed the command line interface for AWS on my old Mac. However, when I transferred all of this laptop's content to a new Macbook, aws doesn't work anymore. Typing `aws` on command line simply returns `killed`.

If I migrated all of the data from my former laptop, then my aws credentials should still work, no? Or could this be a compatibility problem? The older laptop had an Inteli7 processor, and the new one has the M1 chip.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the update to M1 mac - just had the same on M1 Mac Mini.

My solution:
run "brew install awscli" to check the app is installed
My response was that app is unlinked

run "brew link awscli"
response that Target already exists - so I decided to force the issue:

run "brew link --overwrite awscli"

This seems to have fixed my issue and now aws cli appears to be working.

At least, it now lets me access aws configure to continue.

I'll add more if it throws any errors once I run a few commands.

roy.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if .aws folder exists in the User diretory. If yes, then check if the path to the folder is mentioned in the .bash_profile file.

If the .aws folder does not exists then you might to install it again.

Also since you mentioned it is new mac with M1 chip then it could be a version issue too.